# How to return select option value?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This is my Html

```html
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="position-relative form-group">
      <label class="">Status</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="txtStatus" name="Status">
        <option value="A">Active</option>
        <option value="I">Inactive</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

how to do something like this is asp.net mvc?

```html
<option value="A" <%if Status="A" then%>Selected
  <%end if%>>Active</option>
<option value="I" <%if Status="I" then%>Selected
  <%end if%>>Inactive</option>
```

**@Model.Status** is my value.

How to Do like this :

```html
<option value="A" <%if @Model.Status="A" then%>Selected
  <%end if%>>Active</option>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to do is to use the `@Html.DropDownListFor` helper method. In the Model we need to introduce a property for available statuses that can be selected.

```
public class ViewModel
{

    public string Status { get;set;}
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Statuses { get;set;}

    public ViewModel()
    {
         Statuses= new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem {Text = "-- Select Status --", Value = ""},
            new SelectListItem {Text = "Active", Value = "A"},
            new SelectListItem {Text = "InActive", Value = "I"}
        };
    }

}
```

and in view then we can write :

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Status, Model.Statuses, 
                      new { @class ="form-control" , id ="txtStatus"})
```

It will generate html something similar to :

```
<select class="form-control" id="txtStatus" name="Status">
    <option value="A">Active</option>
    <option value="I">Inactive</option>
  </select>
```

### UPDATE:

You can do with plain html like:

```
<option value="A" @(Model.Status =="A" ? "selected" : "")>Active</option>
<option value="I" @(Model.Status =="I" ? "selected" : "")>Inactive</option>
```

Comment: Sajjab i know the what you do using dropDownListFor but my senior want the html style ... don't wan to use the style u do... that why i ask for help.

Comment: @BrantleyOng add the plain html way

Comment: Thank.. so its can us shorthand

Comment: @BrantleyOng you are welcome, you can appreciate the effort by upvote the post and mark it as answer if it was helpful :)